# how to migrate mailbox from cpanel to smartermail

Tags: migration, cpanel, smartercsv

Is there anyway for me to migrate mailbox from cpanel mail to smartermail?

I've google regarding to this issue but do not find any clue of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

[1] Use SmarterMail import email functionality:

- Log into SmarterMail as a user.
- Click the **Settings** icon.
- Expand the **My Settings** and **Advanced Settings** folders in the navigation pane.
- Click **Mailbox Migration**.
- The mailbox migration tool will open in a new window. Follow the on-screen instructions to import email and collaboration data from a third-party mail server to your SmarterMail mailbox.

[2] Second option is, download all emails using POP3 in your local system and then configure your SmarterMail email account as IMAP. Now, sync your download emails to your IMAP folder.

Comment: I've try your method and it is really worked. Thank you. However only inbox that are migrated. The sent item are not. Do you have any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: I haven't tested any other options so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [IMAPCOPY tool](https://code.google.com/archive/p/imapcopy/downloads) to migrate the entire mailbox, however, I do not issue any guarantee that it will work for you!

Comment: how to use the imap copy tool?

Comment: You should refer the article from https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapcopy

I tried it and it worked for me!